# XPATH results into empty string

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, rvest

```
url <- read_html('https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo_sof/27/35/1?')
valuation <- html_nodes(url,xpath='//*[(@id = "ngo_state_p")]')
valuation
class(valuation)
valuation1 <- html_text(valuation)
valuation1
```

the result of above code is empty string?is there any way out to get the exact value.
ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/62/35/1 click on the name of first NGO AdityaNatyaAcademy,under that pop check the value for state for registration i.e ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS

Answer (score 0):

Your individual NGO data is coming in ajax requests in the background. Below is the javascript code that's fetching your data.

Function: `function show_ngo_info(ngo_id)` (in the same page...)

```
$.post("https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", {
         id: ngo_id,
         csrf_test_name:get_csrf_token()
        }
```

It's using csrf token, which may complicate your automation a little bit. But, you should still be able to retrieve data with this. Let me know how it goes.

The data is being fetched on NGO link click in the background, and hence you are getting empty string when trying to read the data before that.

Comment: see,i want to extract the webpage through R,I am using the above code and getting theempty string and I have copied the xpath for the value I want to get i.e ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS ,only fortesting i have considered a sample but I want to extract the complete pop up.

Comment: Understood, perform post request as per the code in my answer above. You need to know ngo_ids for each of the NGOs you wanna retrieve data for. And you also need to send the csrf token with your request. Let me know for further clarification.

Comment: The URL you are using just shows up template, and the JavaScript request that goes in the background fetches the data and populates the fields. Hence, suggest performing your request to the URL in my answer.

Comment: If Python works for you, I may be able to help you with a working sample. Please confirm.